# Ajax : Delete record from database in asp.net mvc without reload the page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to delete mobile form database i.e. **MS SQL Server** in **ASP.NET MVC**. I have done it successfully with the help of **Ajax**. But I need to reload the page then it shows me the correct results.

**Index.cshtml**

```
$(function () {
        $(".DeleteMobile").click(function () {
            var DeleteId = $(this).data("deleteid");
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Mobile/DeleteMobile/" + DeleteId,
                type: "Post"
            }).done(function () {
                getAllMobiles();
                }).error(function () {
                    alert("Something Went Wrong.");
                });
        });
    });
    function getAllMobiles() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Mobile/Index",
            type: "Get"
        }).done(function () {
            alert("All Mobiles get");
        });
    }
```

my problem is in above code. I never want to reload the page after click on delete button. 
**MobileController.cs**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
            {
                MobileHandler mh = new MobileHandler();
                List<Mobile> Mobiles = mh.GetMobiles();
                return View(Mobiles);
            }
    public ActionResult DeleteMobile(int id)
        {
            MobileHandler mh = new MobileHandler();
            mh.DeleteMobile(id);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

Anybody please suggest me, what should I do?

Comment: you can not redirect to another page when you call an action via Ajax-call, the simplest approach is to reload the page on client side by `window.location.reload()` and return `OK()` in your DeleteMobile action

Comment: please explore your answer.

Answer (score 0):

with ajax call you can use json result to pass data or result from controller, you can not redirect to any another action method 
however you can achive this by this change in your controller

```
public JsonResult DeleteMobile(int id = 0)
{
      MobileHandler mh = new MobileHandler();
      mh.DeleteMobile(id);
      // if data is deleted then return true else return false
      return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}

$(function () {
    $(".DeleteMobile").click(function () {
        var DeleteId = $(this).data("deleteid");

        $.ajax({
            url: "/Mobile/DeleteMobile/" + DeleteId,
            type: "Post"
        }).done(function (result) {
            if (result == 'True') {
                alert('data is deleted successfully');
            }
            else {
                alert('Error Please Try again..');
            }

        }).error(function () {
            alert("Something Went Wrong.");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: window.location.reload(); is not looking best approach. Because my requirement is without reload the page... this line of code is reloading the page.

Comment: you can remove line window.location.reload();

Answer (score 0):

I've resolved my problem. By just adding some lines of code in my case. As you can see below.

```
$(function () {
        $(".DeleteMobile").click(function () {
            var button = $(this);
            var DeleteId = $(this).data("deleteid");
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Mobile/DeleteMobile/" + DeleteId,
                type: "Post"
            }).done(function () {
                $(button).parents("tr").remove();
                }).error(function () {
                    alert("Something Went Wrong.");
                });
        });
    });
```

instead of this code

```
$(function () {
        $(".DeleteMobile").click(function () {
            var DeleteId = $(this).data("deleteid");
            debugger;
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Mobile/DeleteMobile/" + DeleteId,
                type: "Post"
            }).done(function () {
                getAllMobiles();
                }).error(function () {
                    alert("Something Went Wrong.");
                });
        });
    });
    function getAllMobiles() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/Mobile/Index",
            type: "Get"
        }).done(function () {
            alert("All Mobiles get");
        });
    }
```